# Notice: Array to string conversion when including variable in query

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

$awal and $akhir is datetime which insert manual by user but i received error. I hoping anyone can help me fix this problem ..

Here's the code

```
$sql_hit="SELECT count(*) FROM komitmen k,relasibisnis r WHERE
k.tgl_bukti BETWEEN '$awal' AND '$akhir'
AND r.koderelasi=k.relasi
AND k.status_komitmen=0 $sqlmpp $umur";

$sql="select k.*,r.namarelasi
from komitmen k,relasibisnis r WHERE
k.tgl_bukti BETWEEN '$awal' AND '$akhir'
and r.koderelasi=k.relasi
and k.status_komitmen=0 $sqlmpp $umur";         

$hasil=pager_query($sql,40,0,$sql_hit);
```

Comment: Why do you have a `array(query string)` -> `array($sql_hit)`as your 2nd param?

Comment: i try to get two table from two query $hasil=db_query($sql,40,0,$sql_hit);

Comment: `$hasil=db_query($sql,40,0,$sql_hit);` is completely invalid syntax if you are using drupal's [`db_query($query, array $args = array(), array $options = array())`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7.x) You can't have 2 query strings in 1 `db_query()` call.

Comment: You should be parameterizing these queries and see ^.

Comment: ok i undestand that dude thank u very much, but i asking how to including $awal and $akhir in query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic example of [db_query()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7.x) for your $awal and $akhir-

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM komitmen k,relasibisnis r WHERE k.tgl_bukti BETWEEN :awal AND :akhir";

$query = db_query($sql, array(':awal' => $awa, ':akhir' => $akhir));
```

Hope! It will help you.